# clipping regions

Tags: silverlight, stackpanel

I have a grid, with a stackpanel on the top.
I have built a mouse over animation that makes images on the stack panel bigger on the mouse over.

How do I take away the clipping region(s) so that the images can grow outside of the stackpanel and cover what is under them?

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" x:Name="pagesColumn"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Width="Auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Background="Red" >
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a RenderTransform ?

I have used this once in order to implement a zooming feature; and the zoomed control was growing outside of its parent (i.e. not clipped).